# Does Windows NT before version 4 (also) have built-in dual-boot support?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bootloader

The Windows NT flavour of Microsoft Windows has had the built-in ability, without needing third-party add-on "boot managers", to dual boot with other (Microsoft) operating systems since at least version 4.  I can find questions here on SuperUser dealing with dual-booting Windows NT 4 and Windows 2000 ([a.k.a. Windows NT 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases)) with other operating systems, such as:

- [Dual boot nt4 and windows 98](https://superuser.com/questions/73767/)
- [Add MS-DOS boot option to Windows 2000](https://superuser.com/questions/664997/)

And there are Microsoft Knowledgebase articles dealing with this:

- [*How to Triple Boot to Windows NT, Windows 95/98, and MS-DOS*](http://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/157992)
- [*How to Dual Boot Windows 98 and Windows NT 4.0 with FAT16 or NTFS Volumes*](http://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/243896)

But what about versions before version 4?  Could Windows NT 3.51, 3.5, or 3.1 dual boot with other (Microsoft) operating systems, with no third-party tools, too?

Comment: `Windows XP` is the first consumer version that came with the `Windows NT` kernel.  So much of your question basically repeats itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, XP was the first NT based consumer version of Windows. The original NT was for workstations and servers. I got that. But what does that have to do with the question? How does a question repeat itself? Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you saying that Windows NT 3.1 was in fact the first Windows system that had the multi boot capability built into it? I could not care less if it's a "consumer" Windows or not.

Comment: I said nothing about `Windows NT 3.1`

Comment: *"Windows Vista is based on NT kernel, as is Windows 7, 8 and 10. But it doesn't mean they use NTLDR at all."*  That is exactly what it means....

Comment: Several of the people who voted to close this question the first time have just voted to close it a second time.  It wasn't a well written question.  Try writing your question like this.

Comment: How is this off topic as when Microsoft still provides these operating systems on MSDN?

Comment: @Louis That may be, but they are no longer supported.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does.
It bundles an OS Loader exactly like NT4

Comment: Can you write some guidelines and refer the user to some sites in order to provide a good answer?